# Script needs to find last in row, not sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I saw another thread [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35858108/script-suggestion-to-insert-a-timestamp-when-button-is-pressed?answertab=oldest#tab-top) with a solution to my start stop issue except it is written to find the last cell in the whole book. I need this for just rows A (for start), and row B (for stop) as I will have other data on the sheet.

I also need to be able to do the same function for multiple sheets... so start and stops just for that sheet.

[image: My sheet]

Here is the current code I am using...

[image: Current Script]

Comment: Can you add your current script as a text instead of the image?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- When you run the script of `startTime()`, you want to put `new Date()` to the cell of the next row of the last row of the column "A".
- When you run the script of `stopTime()`, you want to put `new Date()` to the cell of the next row of the last row of the column "B".
- You want to run the script for the specific sheets you expect.

`getLastRow` returns the last row of all columns. When you want to retrieve the last row of the specific column, it is required to check it using a script instead of the method of `getLastRow`. So, from your sample Spreadsheet shown in your image, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
const sheetNames = ["Line1",,,]; // Please set the sheet names you want to run the script.

// Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44563639
Object.prototype.get1stNonEmptyRowFromBottom = function (columnNumber, offsetRow = 1) {
  const search = this.getRange(offsetRow, columnNumber, this.getMaxRows()).createTextFinder(".").useRegularExpression(true).findPrevious();
  return search ? search.getRow() : offsetRow;
};

function startTime() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if (!sheetNames.includes(sheet.getName())) return;
  const row = sheet.get1stNonEmptyRowFromBottom(1) + 1;
  sheet.getRange(row, 1).setValue(new Date());
}

function stopTime() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if (!sheetNames.includes(sheet.getName())) return;
  const row = sheet.get1stNonEmptyRowFromBottom(2) + 1;
  sheet.getRange(row, 2).setValue(new Date());
}
```

#### Note:

- If you don't want to put the value to the column "B" when the column "A" is blank, please modify `sheet.getRange(row, 2).setValue(new Date());` in `stopTime()` as follows.

  ```
    const range = sheet.getRange(row, 2);
    if (range.offset(0, -1).isBlank()) return;
    range.setValue(new Date());
  ```

#### Reference:

- Related thread

  - [Determining the last row in a single column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17632165)

Comment: Fantastic! Works perfect. Thank you so much.